# How to make an image handler in NancyFx

Tags: image, outputstream, nancy

I'm struggling to output an Image from byte[] out of my database in NancyFX to a web output stream. I don't have sample code close enough to even show at this point. I was wondering if anyone has tackled this problem and could post a snippet? I basically just want to return image/jpeg from a byte array stored in my database and out put it to the web rather than a physical file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just to build on @TheCodeJunkie's answer, you can build a "byte array response" very easily like this:

```cs
public class ByteArrayResponse : Response
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Byte array response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="body">Byte array to be the body of the response</param>
    /// <param name="contentType">Content type to use</param>
    public ByteArrayResponse(byte[] body, string contentType = null)
    {
        this.ContentType = contentType ?? "application/octet-stream";

        this.Contents = stream =>
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.Write(body);
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use the Response.AsX syntax it's a simple extension method on top:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Response FromByteArray(this IResponseFormatter formatter, byte[] body, string contentType = null)
    {
        return new ByteArrayResponse(body, contentType);
    }
}
```

Then in your route you can just use:

```cs
Response.FromByteArray(myImageByteArray, "image/jpeg");
```

You could also add a processor to use a byte array with content negotiation, I've added a quick sample of that to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4605541)

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding on the solution, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a way to make browser cache the byte array response of the request? So that the handler will not work again for the same url?

Comment: That's terrible, that cache's the bytes in memory. Can't you stream directly (using minimal memory)?

Answer (score 12):

In your controller, return Response.FromStream with a stream of bytes of the image.  It used to be called AsStream in older versions of nancy.

```cs
Get["/Image/{ImageID}"] = parameters =>
{
     string ContentType = "image/jpg";
     Stream stream = // get a stream from the image.

     return Response.FromStream(stream, ContentType);
};
```

Comment: How are you supposed to close the source stream with this API? Terrible.

Comment: The source stream is disposed automatically later -https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/786

Comment: You have to make sure that the stream position is set to the beginning of the stream: `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`, since `FromStream` won't do it for you.

Answer (score 8):

From Nancy you can return a new `Response` object. It's `Content` property is of type `Action<Stream>` so you can just create a delegate that writes your byte array to that stream

```
var r = new Response();
r.Content = s => {
   //write to s
};
```

Don't forget to set the `ContentType` property (you could use `MimeTypes.GetMimeType` and pass it the name, including extension) There is also a `StreamResponse`, that inherits from `Response` and provides a different constructor (for a bit nicer syntax you can use `return Response.AsStream(..)` in your route.. just syntax candy)

Comment: Thanks for help, I like the alternate solutions you presented.

Comment: Looks like the property name changed to `Contents`.